# Change Username and Password used for docusign integration

Tags: docusignapi

We are working on an integreation with the Docusign API. I have a very simple problem with the username and password that get used when calling the API.

According to the Preferences->API->API and Integrator Key Information page the username and password to be used when call the webservice is the docusign global admin. This is obviously a highly privileged account with regards to Docusign. Aside from the priviledge issue its also my company email address - which isn't appropriate for a business critical function.

Is there a way to change the account that is used when calling the web services?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you don't *need* to use the username and password listed on the API Integration page, though I'd argue the way its worded suggests you do.

Resolving the issue is as simple as creating a new, less privileged account and using that during the web service call. We have resolved it by using a generic "service" user that we've set up in docusign.